# This variable equals this one

Tags: vb.net

If I do this:

```
Dim w As MyClass = otherObject
```

where "otherObject" is another variable containing an instance of MyClass, I can be sure that w is a completely different variable? I mean, whatever changes I do to w, will NOT affect otherObject, right?

Comment: "I mean, whatever changes I do to w, will NOT affect otherObject, right?" Is that what happened when you tried it ;) For what its worth, if `MyClass` is immutable, then you can freely "change" it without affecting the original object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are just pointers to instances of objects in memory. When you assign the variable `w` to point at `otherObject` they both point at the same object in memory. Making changes to one **will** affect the other.

If you are wanting to make `w` a clone of `otherObject` you can refer to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Clone.aspx) codeproject aritcle.

Comment: Oh dear. My project is now messed up, it seems. Ha, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

No, it won't. They are different objects.